# Using JSON.Net to extract Array Name from the items it contains

Tags: arrays, json, json.net

If I have the following JSON Object read in from a file, what would be a good approach for finding finding and returning the array name of "function" if all I know is the elements being:
"functionId": null, "name": "GameUpdate" and "GameEngine": "None"

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "command": "Query",
      "Type": "Search",
      "id": null,
      "name": "Updates",
      "serviceType": "GameUpdates",
      "status": "Active",
      "isRunning": false,
      "server": "GameServer1",
      "function": [
        {
          "functionId": null,
          "name": "GameUpdate",
          "GameEngine": "None"
        }
      ],
      "system": "Game_System_007",
      "ProcessingTime": "2011-09-05T12:22:21.3809181-01:00",
      "Version": "v1.0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks All!

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) API to find it:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

string arrayName = obj["data"]
    .Children<JObject>()
    .SelectMany(jo => jo.Properties())
    .Where(jp => jp.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array && 
                 jp.Value.Children<JObject>()
                         .Any(jo => (string)jo["functionId"] == null && 
                                    (string)jo["name"] == "GameUpdate" && 
                                    (string)jo["GameEngine"] == "None"))
    .Select(jp => jp.Name)
    .FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(arrayName);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CffG0g